# Размеры области графика(Chart)

Tags: c#, winforms

Использую компонент Chart для отрисовки некоего графика. Размер самого компонента Chart прямоугольный(ширина в пикселях больше высоты). А вот размер области графика должен быть строго квадратным. Как делаю:

```
ChartGraphic.ChartAreas[0].Position.Height = 70;
ChartGraphic.ChartAreas[0].Position.Width = 70;
ChartGraphic.ChartAreas[0].Position.X = 3;
ChartGraphic.ChartAreas[0].Position.Y = 10;
```

Получается так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно - сама координатная система не квадратная. Как правильно её настроить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У графика есть свойство ChartArea, а у него, в свою очередь, свойство Position, которое позволяет в процентах указать положение и размер графика относительно родительского контрола. Примерный код, который нужно поместить в событие Resize, чтобы график был всегда строго квадратным:

```
ChartGraphic.ChartAreas[0].Position.X = 3;
ChartGraphic.ChartAreas[0].Position.Y = 1;
if (ChartGraphic.Width < ChartGraphic.Height)
{
    ChartGraphic.ChartAreas[0].Position.Width = 90;
    ChartGraphic.ChartAreas[0].Position.Height = (float)(ChartGraphic.Width / 100.0 * 90 * 100) / ChartGraphic.Height;
}
else
{
    ChartGraphic.ChartAreas[0].Position.Height = 90;
    ChartGraphic.ChartAreas[0].Position.Width = (float)(ChartGraphic.Height / 100.0 * 90 * 100) / ChartGraphic.Width;
}
```